# Netty: channel.write hangs on disconnect

Tags: java, exception, netty, disconnect

I have the following situation:

A new channel connection is opened in this way:

```
    ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(
             new OioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    icapClientChannelPipeline = new ICAPClientChannelPipeline();           
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(icapClientChannelPipeline);
    ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
    channel = future.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();
```

This is working as expected.

Stuff is written to the channel in the following way:

```
channel.write(chunk)
```

This also works as expected when the connection to the server is still alive. But if the server goes down (machine goes offline), the call hangs and doesn't return.

I confirmed this by adding log statements before and after the `channel.write(chunk)`. When the connection is broken, only the log statement before is displayed.

1. What is causing this? I thought these calls are all async and return immediately? I also tried with NioClientSocketChannelFactory, same behavior.
2. I tried to use `channel.getCloseFuture()` but the listener never gets called, I tried to check the channel before writing with `channel.isOpen()`, `channel.isConnected()` and `channel.isWritable()` and they are always true...
3. How to work around this? No exception is thrown and nothing really happens... Some questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988343/can-netty-reliably-detect-channel-close-disconnect) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595541/cant-detect-server-side-offline-in-netty) indicate that it isn't possible to detect a channel disconnect without a heartbeat. But I can't implement a heartbeat because I can't change the server side.

Environment: Netty 3, JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this one on my own last week so I'll add the answer for completness.

I was wrong in 3. because I thought I'll have to change both the client and the server side for a heartbeat. As described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595541/cant-detect-server-side-offline-in-netty) you can use the `IdleStateAwareHandler` for this purpose. I implemented it like this:

The IdleStateAwareHandler:

```
public class IdleStateAwareHandler extends IdleStateAwareChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void channelIdle(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, IdleStateEvent e) {
        if (e.getState() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
            e.getChannel().write("heartbeat-reader_idle");
        }
        else if (e.getState() == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE) {
            Logger.getLogger(IdleStateAwareHandler.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.WARNING, "WriteIdle detected, closing channel");
            e.getChannel().close();
            e.getChannel().write("heartbeat-writer_idle");
        }
        else if (e.getState() == IdleState.ALL_IDLE) {
            e.getChannel().write("heartbeat-all_idle");
        }
    }
}
```

The PipeLine:

```
public class ICAPClientChannelPipeline implements ICAPClientPipeline {

        ICAPClientHandler icapClientHandler;
        ChannelPipeline pipeline;

        public ICAPClientChannelPipeline(){
            icapClientHandler = new ICAPClientHandler();
        pipeline = pipeline(); 
            pipeline.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(new HashedWheelTimer(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), 5, 5, 5));
            pipeline.addLast("idleStateAwareHandler", new IdleStateAwareHandler());
            pipeline.addLast("encoder",new IcapRequestEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("chunkSeparator",new IcapChunkSeparator(1024*4));
            pipeline.addLast("decoder",new IcapResponseDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast("chunkAggregator",new IcapChunkAggregator(1024*4));
            pipeline.addLast("handler", icapClientHandler);            
        }

        @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return pipeline;
    }                     
}
```

This detects any read or write idle state on the channel after 5 seconds.
As you can see it is a little bit ICAP-specific but this doesn't matter for the question.

To react to an idle event I need the following listener:

```
channel.getCloseFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            doSomething();
    }
});
```